# Find the solution to recurrence relation and initial conditions. Use an iterative approach.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$A(n)=3A(n-1)+1, A(0)=1$$

the solution from the textbook is $$A(n)=\dfrac{3^{n+1}-1}2$$

But I am having trouble to understand how we get this answer.

Comment: If you want a proof, you might want to try induction...

Comment: Hint:  let $B_n=A_n+\frac 12$.  Show that $B_{n+1}=3B_n$.

Comment: FYI, this is a relatively simple case of a [linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation). The Wikipedia article provides several ways to solve these types of equations, so that may help to explain how the textbook solution was possibly obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have suggested alternative approaches, but here is an iterative approach, as requested:
\begin{align}
A(n) &= 3 A(n-1)+1\\
&= 3 (3 A(n-2)+1)+1\\
&= 3^2 A(n-2)+3+1 \\
&= 3^2 (3 A(n-3)+1)+3+1 \\
&= 3^3 A(n-3)+3^2+3+1 \\
&= \dots \\
&= 3^n A(0)+3^{n-1}+\dots+3^2+3+1 \\
&= 3^n +3^{n-1}+\dots+3^2+3+1 \\
&= \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{3-1} &&\text{(finite geometric series)}\\
&= \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: I did not find the exact solution, but I found: ((3+3^n)n)/2+1 also works. Thank you

Comment: The recurrence relation and initial condition uniquely determine the sequence here.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is via Proof by Induction:

First we show the statement ($A_n=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$) holds for $n=0$

$$LHS: A(0)=1, RHS: A(0)=\frac{3^1-1}{2}=1$$
so true for $n=0$

Then we assume it is true for $n=k$, i.e. $A(k)=\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$

and use that to show it holds for $n=k+1$, i.e.

$$3A(k)+1=\frac{3^{k+2}-1}{2}$$

I leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

$A_1=4$.   For $n\ge2,$ $A_n=3A_{n-1}+1$ and $A_{n-1}=3A_{n-2}+1$, so $A_n-4A_{n-1}+3A_{n-2}=0;$

this is a homogeneous recurrence with characteristic equation $ (\lambda-3)(\lambda-1)=0,$

so the solution is of the form $A_n=C\times3^n+D\times1^n.$

From $A_0=1$ and $A_1=4$, we see that $C=\frac{3}2$ and $D=\frac{-1}2.$

Answer (score 0):

Induction will easily verify that this is the answer but does not tell you how to derive the answer directly from the recurrence formula. To do this you could use a generating function. Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n x^n$.

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n x^n \\
&=& 1+ 3x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n-1} x^{n-1} +  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  x^n \\
&=& 1+ 3x f(x)+  \frac{x}{1-x}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do a bit of algebra & some partial fractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)= \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-3x)} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{1-3x} +\frac{1}{1-x} \right) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Finally geometrically expand & equate coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly differently:

$$A(n)=3A(n-1)+1~~~~~(1)$$
then $A(2)=4$ and
$$A(n+1_)=3A)n)+1~~~~(2)$$
Subtract (1) from (2) to get
$$A(n+1)-A(n)=3[A(n)-A(n-1)] \implies B(n)=3B(n-1) \implies B(n)=3^n c$$ $$\implies A(n+1)-A(n)=3^n c~~~~(3).$$
Next by telescopic summing starting from $n=1$, we get 
$$A(n+1)-A(1)=[3+3^2+3^3+...+3^n]c \implies A(n+1)=\frac{3(3^n-1)}{2}c+A(1).$$
Put $n=2$, to get $c=1$, then $$A(n+1)=\frac{3^{n+1}}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \implies A(n)=\frac{3^n-1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To make life easier with $$A_n=3A_{n-1}+1$$ let $A_n=B_n+k$ and replace to make
$$B_n+k=3B_{n-1}+3k+1\implies B_n=3B_{n-1}+2k+1$$ If you make $k=-\frac 12$, you then have
$$B_n=3B_{n-1}$$ Solve it for $B_n$ (this is simple) and go back to $A_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$$
A(n)=3A(n-1)+1\quad\text{and}\quad A(0)=1
$$
Multiply by $3^{-n}$
$$
3^{-n}A(n)=3^{1-n}A(n-1)+3^{-n}
$$
Substitute $B(n)=3^{-n}A(n)$
$$
B(n)=B(n-1)+3^{-n}\quad\text{and}\quad B(0)=1
$$
Apply the [sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)
$$
B(n)=\frac{1-3^{-n-1}}{1-3^{-1}}
$$
Back substitute to get
$$
A(n)=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}2
$$